# How to iterate over dic and list

Tags: python, python-2.7, text-analysis

I've a folder with a bunch of `.SQL` files that I want match against an extraction of `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` (only `TABLE_NAME` and `COLUMN_NAME` columns that are on `column_list.csv`).

My objective is to have a relation of tables/columns used for each report, generating an output like: 
`sql_file_name.sql | table_name | column_name`

It seems that when I moved from second to third nested loop the variables got 'out of reach', `Python (2.7.13)` treats them as new:

```
import os
import csv

path = "./search_files"
folder = os.listdir(path)

search_dict = csv.DictReader(open("column_list.csv"))

for files in folder:
    files = os.path.join(path, files)
    file = open(files, "r")
    sql = file.readlines()

    sql = [x.strip() for x in sql] # Remove \n

    hit_count = 0

    for i in sql:
        i = i.upper() # Make SQL code UPPERCASE
        print str(hit_count) + ": " + i # i has values here
        hit_count = hit_count + 1

        for row in search_dict:
            print str(hit_count) + ": " + i # i is blank here
            hit_count = hit_count + 1

            if row['TABLE_NAME'] in i or row['COLUMN_NAME'] in i:
                print row['TABLE_NAME'] + " | " + row['COLUMN_NAME']
```

Comment: Curious, can you paste the output as well? I suspect you have some empty lines in your sql files...

Comment: Sure I can. This is an extract from the output of first print:
`455: CASE WHEN LSZ55EXCC2 = '05' THEN '07' ELSE LSZ55EXCC2 END,
1456: ' ',
1457: IMLITM,
1458: LSZ55TABC,
1459: LSZ55COMP,
1460: LSZ55AENT,
1461: LSZ55MENT,
1462: 0,
1463: `

This is from the secound one:
`6469:
6470: 
6471: 
6472: 
6473: 
6474: `

And the last print doesn't output

Comment: Hey wait a second, it is possible that your `search_dict` is empty!!! By the look of your output. So make sure `column_list.csv` is proper. Can you cat `column_list.csv` and show the first few lines by editing the question?

Comment: Or you could do a `print len(search_dict)` just before the innermost `for` loop.

Comment: what does `len(search_dict)` output?

Comment: Interesting, it returns an error: `    print len(search_dict)
AttributeError: DictReader instance has no attribute '__len__' `

Comment: Try `len(list(search_dict))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that `search_dict` is an iterator, and you're trying to iterate on it several times. That doesn't work. After the first time you reach the end of the input file, the iterator will remain empty forever.

There are a few ways you can fix that. The easiest is probably to dump the values from the iterator into a list:

```
search_dict = list(csv.DictReader(open("column_list.csv")))
```

The only real downside to this approach is that it might use a lot of memory if your CSV file is huge.

Alternatively, you could "cheat" a bit with the iterator protocol. Normally an iterator that has raised a `StopIteration` exception should continue to do so forever. But files are iterators that let you cheat a bit. If you `seek` the file back to the start, you can iterate over its contents again. This *may* let you continue iterating other iterators that are taking their inputs from the file you rewound. There is no guarantee that this will always work. It does for `csv.reader` and `csv.DictReader`, but wouldn't work for a generator function written in pure Python.

So here's one way you could adapt your code:

```
search_file = open("column_list.csv")        # keep a reference to this file for later
search_dict = csv.DictReader(search_file)

for files in folder:
    #...
    for i in sql:
        #...

        search_file.seek(0)                  # ensure we're at the start of the file
        for row in search_dict:
            #...
```

Another approach would be to simply reopen the file each time you start the inner loop.

Another suggestion unrelated to your looping issue: You should probably be a bit more careful about closing files. This is pretty easy to do in Python if you use the `with` statement. Rather than doing something like `var = open(filename)`, use `with open(filename) as var:` and indent all the code that uses the file into a block under it. The file will be closed automatically when you exit the indented block (even if you exit due to an exception). My examples above kept your current style of opening files, but if I was writing them for my own code, I'd write:

```
with open("column_list.csv") as search_file:
    search_dict = list(csv.DictReader(search file))

# rest of the code is not indented extra
```

Or for the `seek(0)` version:

```
with open("column_list.csv") as search_file:   # the whole code is indented under this block
    search_dict = csv.DictReader(search_file)

    for files in folder:    # files is a really misleading variable name
        files = os.path.join(path, files)
        with open(files, "r") as file:
            sql = file.readlines()  # only a single line needs to be indented extra this time

        #...
```

And one final suggestion: Use better variable names. Part of the confusing from this issue was due to the name `search_dict`. That name makes it sound like it should contain a single dictionary. But that's not what it actually was in the code (it was actually a `csv.DictReader` instance, which you were using as an iterator). Similarly, your `files` variable (created by the outermost `for` loop) is also misleading. It conatins a single filename, not several files (which the plural name suggests).

Comment: my bad I assumed `search_dict` would act like a normal `dict`. One you could iterate over any number of times, without the need to `seek(0)`